# Aptana Studio 3.1.1 on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3 - vertical scrollbar frustrations

Tags: osx-lion, scrollbar, aptana

This morning I accepted an Aptana Studio 3 upgrade to build 3.1.1.201204131931.

Prior to the update, I had a clear and permanently visible vertical scroll slider on each open file window. These now appear to have been replaced with a newer Mac OS style scroller which is troublesome to activate, disappears immediately the mouse moves away and so murky it was hours before I even noticed it was there...

The mew behaviour has a profound effect on my efficiency, as I am now far from intuitively aware of my location in the source files.

Is there some way of restoring the original behavior? Defaults restoral throughout and many hours of search of various preferences settings, online forums and user guides have brought nothing. Very frustrating..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by default Lion only shows scrollbars when scrolling.

You can change this through OS X preferences under "General". Change the "Show scroll bars:" option to "Always".